# how can i ajax url dynamically with django template?

Tags: python, ajax, django

like same problem but not solve--> [Send Dynamic AJAX URL in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19535800/send-dynamic-ajax-url-in-django)

i want to data extraction by using dynamically url.

urls.py

```
url(r'^(?P<idx>\d+)/rapor/$',ReportView.as_view(),name='rapor'),
url(r'^(?P<idx>\d+)/rapor/hamveri/$',ChartData.as_view(),name='hamveri'),
```

report.html

```
var endpoint ='/analiz/{{ data.id }}/rapor/hamveri/';
var defaultData = [];
var labels = [];


$.ajax({
method: "GET",
url: endpoint,
success: function(data){
     labels = data.labels;
     defaultData = data.default;
     setChart()
},
error: function(error_data){
     console.log("error");
     console.log(error_data)
 }});
```

well-done data send to web address but i can't data extraction from this url

[http://127.0.0.1:8000/analiz/33/rapor/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sK07c.png)

how can i fixed this problem?

if i edit report.html

report.html

```
var endpoint ='/analiz/33/rapor/hamveri/';
```

perfect-run web site, it can data extraction from  'analiz/33/rapor/hamveri/'

and so;
[http://127.0.0.1:8000/analiz/33/rapor/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVPcc.png)

but not dynamically url :(

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: If you inspect element over your HTML, what do you see in place of "  var endpoint ='/analiz/{{ data.id }}/rapor/hamveri/';  " ? Do you see the tag "  {{ data.id }}  " or the value sent by you through your views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can try is:

Write this HTML just before the JavaScript  starts.
Then change the variable:

**var endpoint ='/analiz/{{ data.id }}/rapor/hamveri/';** as described below,

Somewhat like this:

```
<div id="endpoint-url-div" url="{% url 'hamveri' data.id %}" style="display: none;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var endpoint = document.getElementById('endpoint-url-div').getAttribute('url');
    //Now endpoint should have a URL like **/analiz/33/rapor/hamveri/**
    //Add the rest of your JavaScript as it is. 
    var defaultData = [];
    var labels = [];

     $.ajax({
         method: "GET",
         url: endpoint,
         success: function(data){
                  labels = data.labels;
                  defaultData = data.default;
                  setChart()
              },
         error: function(error_data){
                   console.log("error");
                   console.log(error_data)
             },
        });
    </script>
```

Make sure that variable is sent correctly from your views. Make sure you have a variable inside your **context dictionary inside the views.**

views.py must have something like:

```
context = dict()
context['data'] = #Some data model object
```

**EDIT:**

As I can see in your analiz/views.py, you are not sending any **idx** or **model data object** to your repor.html.

Not sending **idx** or **model data object** to repor.html will not give you a url like: `/analiz/33/rapor/hamveri/` inside the variable **endpoint**.

In your views, you have to send a **model object**

```
class ReportView(View):
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    data = UploadFile.objects.get(...) #Get the model object here. Put something like:  user = request.user
    context = {'data' : data}
    return render(request, 'analiz/rapor.html', context)
```

Now in your HTML:

```
<div id="endpoint-url-div" url="{% url 'hamveri' data.id %}" style="display: none;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var endpoint = document.getElementById('endpoint-url-div').getAttribute('url');
    ...
    ...
    ... #Rest of the Javascript# ...
    ...
</script>
```

Comment: @didierdrogba I made an edit. Check if anything is printed in your browser console.

Comment: bro thanks for help but i cant. if you download file, maybe you can http://www.dosya.tc/server9/dwbias/istatistik.rar.html but you didn't again thanks.

Comment: @didierdrogba I read you code and see the problem. I've made an EDIT. Please refer to it and see if it works.

Comment: but i firstly sending to "analiz/idx/rapor/hamveri" by class ChartData(APIView):  then using ajax data extraction from this url. not necessary object.get() function for Reportview, so this class just directly to html page (raport.html) and in raport.html, i can data extraction using ajax jquery. isnt it?

Comment: i think, just editable code ajax method but i dont known how to edit.

Comment: if endpoint variable is dynamically urls, perfect-run web site

Comment: Could you explain dynamically urls using an example? I'm sorry. I don't quite understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, well-done

i make mistake in a critical point.

@shivamsharma said that you are not sending any idx or model data object to your repor.html.

So this function:

```
class ReportView(View):
def get(self, request,idx,*args, **kwargs):
    return render(request, 'analiz/rapor.html', {'dataninidx':idx}) # added new key
```

Then i change variable in report.html

```
var endpoint='/analiz/{{ dataninidx }}/rapor/hamveri/';
```

Yes, the program only works with two changes.

Thanks for your help, @shivam-sharma